Need help in react and flask mongo auth
I am trying to implement a very simple auth for my project
//React code
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Signin.css";
const Signin = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    password: "",
    contactNumber: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit",
        formData
      );
  
      if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
        const token = response.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        console.log("Token received:", token);
      } else {
        console.error("Error:", response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending data:", error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="box">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label className="SigninLabel" htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
          <input
            className="SigninInput"
            type="text"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            value={formData.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />

          <label className="SigninLabel" htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input
          className="SigninInput"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            value={formData.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />

          <label className="SigninLabel" htmlFor="contactNumber">Contact Number:</label>
          <input
          className="SigninInput"
            type="text"
            id="contactNumber"
            name="contactNumber"
            value={formData.contactNumber}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
          />

          <button className="SigninButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signin;


This is my react component meant to send data to backend
//Flask code
@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])
def submit():
    data = request.get_json()
    name = data.get("name")
    password = data.get("password")
    contact_number = data.get("contactNumber")

    existing_user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"contactNumber": contact_number})

    if existing_user:
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=existing_user["_id"])
        return jsonify({"message": "User authenticated", "token": access_token}), 200

    else:
        new_user = {
            "name": name,
            "password": password,
            "contactNumber": contact_number,
            "reports": []
        }
        result = mongo.db.users.insert_one(new_user)
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=str(result.inserted_id))
        return jsonify({"message": "User created", "token": access_token}), 201



this is my flask route meant to recieve that data,check if user exists,and send it to mongodb
I am unable to send auth data to mongo.This is my first time doing auth.Please have  a look at this problem.

ERROR:app:Exception on /submit [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Company\grainScope\project\test-backend\app.py", line 59, in submit
existing_user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"contactNumber": contact_number})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'users'
This is the error i am getting

where is your init mongo.db. The error come from your setup mongo.db is None. you would create connection to mongodb
